# Nircmd not recognized in directory

Tags: windows-10, command-line, nircmd

I've an interesting issue; I added nircmd.exe to my directory by running it as administrator and going through the prompts, and confirmed it was in the directory by looking in C:\Windows. 
Yet whenever I try to call nircmd.exe from command line, I am greeted by the same prompt that I encountered prior to adding nircmd.exe to the directory.

I am at a loss on what to do now, as this seems contrary to how nircmd.exe is supposed to function when placed in the directory.

Comment: What prompts are you talking about?

Comment: @LPChip "If you copy NirCmd utility into your Windows directory, you'll be able to use NirCmd without specifying the full path of nircmd.exe; Do you want to copy NirCmd into your Windows Directory? Yes / No" answered with 'Yes' while running program as Administrator.

Comment: Hmm. I can repro that on Windows 7 ...

Comment: having the same issue here on windows 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This seems contrary to how `nircmd` is supposed to function

It is not really contrary.

- Running `nircmd` by itself (any number of times) will produce this behaviour (which will do the initial setup).

  This allows you to set up a newer version of `nircmd` when one becomes available. There are occasional bug fixes and new commands get added as well.
- However, `nircmd` is intended to be normally used with [additional arguments](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/).

  When you call it with those additional arguments it behaves as expected (it doesn't ask you to do the copy again).